# Can a view be based upon logical groupings and not visual groupings?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

What I mean, is do the elements have to be grouped together visually.

From a data stand point, I have a table on the server called Accounts, which holds environment information like what page the user was on, their name, the location of their picture, and other small bits of information, that is spread through out the one page application visually.

However each row of data represents a model, and I would like a 1 to 1 map to the view.

It is a logical grouping of data but not a visual one.

Is this O.K?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone views conventionally manage one DOM element, and take one model. You *can* make them work otherwise, but it's not a good idea. It's nice when your models line up with the nouns in your project, but it's not a requirement. In this case it sounds like your `Accounts` table mostly lines up with a `User` model - it's got attributes like their name, their avatar, etc - even if it does have some extra metadata attached. I think that would translate into an `Account` model nicely.

However, I'd recommend against insisting on a 1-to-1 mapping between models and views. A large benefit of Backbone is that you can show the same data in your app in a number of different ways, and Backbone will keep them all up to date. Rather than try to construct a giant View that manages the whole page, it's better to think of Backbone views as "partials" or small components that do one thing well. It's common to use a [Backbone router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) to transition the state of your pages, and you may have some Backbone views that have *no* model, and simply render a bunch of sub-views.

For instance, you could have a `NavBarView` that takes an `Account` model and displays a page header. It can show a dropdown menu with the user's name & picture, add a custom "« Back to your previous page" link, and show/hide some links based on whether the user is an admin or not. You could also have an `EditAccountView` that lets a user update their name & picture; it has the same `Account` model, but displays the user data in an edit form instead. Two views, but the same model - and if the `NavBarView` is listening for `change` events on the model, it'll automatically update the page header for you.